# How to import other javascript files with rhino

Tags: javascript, rhino

I can't for the life of me figure out how to import javascript files in javascript under Rhino. Basically, all I want to do is import "some file.js" and be able to use the things in scope there.

I've been trying to mess with Context.currenctContext (compileString and compileReader), but I don't understand how to get the appropriate Scope and I keep getting the exception "Cannot find default value for object" with this code:

```
Context.currentContext.compileString("print('something')", "whatever, 0, null).exec(Context.currentContext, null)
```

It seems pretty silly if I can't create modules that I can then reuse in my javascript programs... Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript (Rhino) use library or include other scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650377/javascript-rhino-use-library-or-include-other-scripts)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[JavaScript (Rhino) use library or include other scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650377/javascript-rhino-use-library-or-include-other-scripts)