# Import js file from another url in Rhino

Tags: javascript, rhino

I am trying to use a rhino js file located at a GitHub repo. Using JS Script Engine: Rhino 1.7.13 version. Is there a way I can achieve this. I cannot place this file as application is on cloud. So, need to refer/load this file.

Answer (score -1):

I found this on StackOverflow (the answer has been validated) :

[How to import other javascript file with Rhino](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5076759/16067048)

Comment: use function is not working.